# Show that all intervals contained in $[0, 1]$ is a semi-algebra

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $J = \{\text{All intervals contained in }[0,1]\}$

I am having trouble showing that the complement of any element of $J$ is equal to a finite disjoint union of elements of $J$.

It seems simple enough - draw a line, cut out one or a few segments, what's left is the disjoint union of elements of $J$. Don't know how to express that mathematically though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element of $J$ is of the form $[a,b], (a,b], [a,b),$ or $(a,b)$ with $0\leq a\leq 1$, $0\leq b\leq 1$ and $a\leq b$.  So, its complement is $[0,a)\cup (b,1]$ or some other appropriate use of ()'s or []'s, which is by definition, a union of two elements of $J$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider an open interval, but the principle is the same with other intervals.

If $(a,b)\subseteq[0,1]$, and $x\notin(a,b)$ then $0\leq x\leq 1$, and at the same time $x\notin(a,b)$ meaning it is not true $a<x<b$.

So it is not true $a<x<b$, then either $x\leq a$ or $b\leq x$. Now combine this with the fact that $0\leq x\leq 1$, and obtain that union of two intervals.